# Java HTML parsing Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, html, parsing, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get the content from `<div class="article__content">` but I got NullPointerException, I dont really know how to solve this as I dont have that much web knowledge maybe I am using the tags incorrectly :/ Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("somelink").get();

        String content = doc.getElementById("article__content").text();
       System.out.println(content);
    }
```

Comment: You actually should provide more information, such as where the exception ocurrs, a stacktrace, etc.

Comment: You said you want to get a `div` by its `class` but you are calling `getElementById`, not `getElementsByClass`. Could that be where the problem lies?

Comment: @Sam thank you :)) That was the problem, I didnt notice that it was getElementById :/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the getElementsByClass function:

```
Elements articles = doc.getElementsByClass("article__content");
```

As there can be more than one div having this class, this function returns an "Elements" object. If you know for shure that there is just one object with this class, you can use this:

```
Element article = doc.getElementsByClass("article__content").first();
```

So if you want to return the text that is written between the `<div>` tags, you just use the `text()` function. So it would look like this:

```
System.out.println(article.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have control over the HTML and there is only one of the element in question, rewrite the HTML to use the `id` attribute instead of `class`. Using `class` when there is guaranteed to be only one element of the class is not recommended practice.